# SocketError when trying to install Ruby Gems for windows XP

Tags: ruby, windows-xp

I am trying to install the `nokogiri`,`selenium-webdriver`,`mechanize` but getting error as below:

```
ruby 1.9.3p374 (2013-01-15) [i386-mingw32]

C:\Documents and Settings\pp>gem install nokogiri
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'nokogiri' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    SocketError: getaddrinfo: No such host is known.  (http://rubygems.org/lates
t_specs.4.8.gz)

C:\Documents and Settings\pp>gem install nokogiri
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'nokogiri' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    SocketError: getaddrinfo: No such host is known.  (http://rubygems.org/lates
t_specs.4.8.gz)

C:\Documents and Settings\pp>gem install selenium-webdriver
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'selenium-webdriver' (>= 0) in any repository

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    SocketError: getaddrinfo: No such host is known.  (http://rubygems.org/lates
t_specs.4.8.gz)

C:\Documents and Settings\pp>gem install selenium
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'selenium' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    SocketError: getaddrinfo: No such host is known.  (http://rubygems.org/lates
t_specs.4.8.gz)
```

Could you help me to get it done?

Comment: Can anyone help me here by saying why it is happening?

Comment: Corporate firewalls, I hate you :)

Comment: Removed the tags: This isn't a Nokogiri, Mechanize or Selenium problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error seems like a proxy issue, 
try the following command

`gem install --http-proxy <your proxy host:port> <your gem name>`

eg.

`gem install --http-proxy http://localhost:8888 selenium-webdriver`

You can also do

`SET HTTP_PROXY=http://%USER%:%PASSWORD%@%SERVER%:%PORT%`

then execute your `gem install`

Comment: `+1` to you!Its working.I tried below `C:\Ruby193>gem install --http-proxy 3.209.30.25:80 nokogiri` and all download has been started.